# Igraph plot corrupts node name

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, igraph

I read a [tutorial for iGraph](https://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html) and met a strange behaviour of `Graph.plot`
I created the simple graph as it is suggested in the tutorial:

```
g = Graph([(0,1), (0,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,2), (2,5), (5,0), (6,3), (5,6)])
g.vs["name"] = ["Alice", "Bob", "Claire", "Dinnis", "Esther", "Frank", "George"]
g.vs["age"] = [25, 31, 18, 47, 22, 23, 50]
g.vs["gender"] = ["f", "m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "m"]
g.es["is_formal"] = [False, False, True, True, True, False, True, False, False]
g.vs["label"] = g.vs["name"]
color_dict = {"m": "blue", "f": "pink"}
g.vs["color"] = [color_dict[gender] for gender in g.vs["gender"]]
layout = g.layout("kk")
```

and use `plot`:

```
plot(g, layout = layout, bbox = (300, 300), margin = 20)
```

The result in Jupyter Notebook is :

[image]

It looks weird. If I do the same in a console, it works just fine.

I'm working on Windows 10, and I installed igraph + pycairo from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycairo). Could the OS be the problem?

Comment: No it's not the OS. I just tried and works fine for me. Do you use python 2 or 3? See my output in the pdf here: https://gofile.io/?c=bOClJy

Comment: did you try to restart the kernel?

Comment: If I save the plot to pdf (like `plot(g, "social_network.pdf"`)), it looks fine in the file. But in the Jupyter cell it still looks like in the screenshot, even after I restarted the kernel. I use python 3.6.